# Fixing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values error in NGINX

Tags: wordpress, nginx, cors

I'm setting up a Wordpress website (e.g. http://api.example.com) in order to consumer its API from another static, HTML/JS website (e.g. https://test.example.com).

Both website are hosted on an Nginx server, and are each configured with a conf file and function properly on their own. `nginx -t` yields no error and I have full access to both websites as expected.

Unfortunately I'm facing issues with CORS.
When attempting to read media (images, videos) content from `api.example.com`, `test.example.com` yields the following error in the browser console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 
'https://api.example.com/wp-json/custom-post/v1/some-data/' 
from origin 'https://test.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: 

The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
'https://test.example.com, https://test.example.com', 
but only one is allowed.
```

Furthermore, on Chrome, this error is followed by a CORB error (`Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://api.example.com/wp-json with MIME type application/json.`).

I have noticed when inspecting the request header in the browser, redundant values for these properties:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true, true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://test.example.com, https://test.example.com
```

Sensing there might be a redundant `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` somewhere, I have looked for it in the `nginx.conf` file and all `conf` files in `sites-enabled`, to no avail. I've also looked within the source code of the Wordpress application, used plugins included, for an injection of this header. There were none to be found.

Finally, I have tried to remove the one line in `api.example.com.conf` adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header — it yields the pure and simple `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error for media content in the browser console. 
Interestingly, it doesn't yield the CORB error for JSON anymore, and `test.example.com` is able to read textual content from JSON files.

Here's the content of the `api.example.com.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root /var/www/example.com/backend;
    server_name api.example.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/unicorn_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/unicorn_error.log;

    charset                     utf-8;
    gzip                        off;

    # Set CORS policy
    set $cors_origin            "";
    set $cors_cred              "";
    set $cors_header            "";
    set $cors_method            "";

    if ($http_origin ~ '^https?:\/\/(localhost|test.example\.com)$') {
        set $cors_origin        $http_origin;
        set $cors_cred          true;
        set $cors_header        $http_access_control_request_headers;
        set $cors_method        $http_access_control_request_method;
    }

    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin      $cors_origin;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials $cors_cred;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers     $cors_header;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods     $cors_method;

    location / {
        index                   index.php index.html;
        try_files               $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    client_max_body_size        50m;

    # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
    rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

    # Prevents hidden files (beginning with a period) from being served
    location ~ /\. {
        access_log              off;
        log_not_found           off;
        deny                    all;
    }

    # Send 'expires' headers and turn off 404 logging
    location ~* ^.+.(xml|ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log              off;
        log_not_found           off;
        expires                 max;
    }

    # Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm or php-cgi server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files               $uri =404;
        include                 /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout    3600s;
        fastcgi_buffer_size     128k;
        fastcgi_buffers         4 128k;
        fastcgi_param           SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass            unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
    }

    # Robots
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Restrictions
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I expect `test.example.com` to consume any content from `api.example.com`, but I can't get to do so fully.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was due to the `rest_send_cors_headers` filter the REST API hooks into `rest_pre_serve_request`. It sent CORS headers with [API requests](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_send_cors_headers/).

It can be shut down with the following action:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
    remove_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers');
}, 15);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Davy, you  saved me  a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_rest_api_init() {
    remove_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers' );
    add_filter( 'rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
        header( 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link', false );
        header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With' );
        // header( 'Vary: Origin', false );

        return $value;
    } );
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'custom_rest_api_init', 15 );
```